# Drainage for a gravel surface lot between buildings that was previously grass?

Tags: driveway, lawn

All four sides of the lot are surrounded by concrete (alley and road) or brick buildings and basements. I'm a bit hesitant to just put a weed mat and gravel over the grass. I'm worried about how rain will drain.

Does it matter? Is there something I should install before laying the gravel?

It's about 20'x100':

[image: Current]

[image]

Proposed:

[image]

Note - red would be concrete (in place of the hill)

Comment: Not specifically "drainage" related, but you'll want to remove (& sell off) the topsoil, not just put fabric and gravel on top of it, unless you like creating long-term problems with your (evidently) new parking area. Beware of buried utilities (have them located and marked before starting work.)

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought to sell the topsoil. Thanks! (Yes 811 was called before digging.)

Answer (score 3):

Depending on local rules, you may need on-site stormwater management (surface slopes to a holding area/soakaway - either on the surface as a vegetated swale, (which offers some bio-filtration of parking lot runoff) or to underground "detention systems" that will hold the influx and let it soak away slowly.

In some areas you may be required to actively filter what goes into an underground system, making the space tradeoff of an aboveground swale with bio-filtration more attractive.

Or you may just need to provide a path out to the street - but the latter option has become less likely as cities/towns work to lower their storm sewer peak volume flow.

Comment: Another possibility would be effectively "permeable pavement," with a #57 or larger stone reservoir beneath the gravel "wear surface."  Obviously it adds cost, but all the SWM options add cost.  Small chance the OP could get away with adding a rain barrel or something to his home's downspout(s).